# Issue using CJuiDatePicker with different formats

Tags: php, yii

I am using **CJuiDatePicker** in my form and I need to use two different formats: `mm/dd/yy` to be shown and `dd/mm/yy` to be sent in `$_POST`.

```
$questionario->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
    'model' => $modeloDoQuestionario,
    'attribute' => 'data_preenchimento',
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => array(
        'showAnim' => 'fold',
        'showButtonPanel' => true,
        'showOn' => 'both',
        'dateFormat' => 'dd/mm/yy',
        'altField' => '#Questionarios_data_preenchimento',
        'altFormat' => 'mm/dd/yy', 
    ),
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'style' => 'height:14px;'
    ),
));
```

This is the field in HTML:

```
<input style="height:14px;" id="Questionarios_data_preenchimento" name="Questionarios[data_preenchimento]" type="text" />
```

But I still get the `mm/dd/yy` format in `$_POST`... What can be wrong?

Comment: the `alt` format your provided is `'altFormat' => 'mm/dd/yy',`

Comment: @DevZer0 Do you think I should use `alt` so? The [reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) shows `altFormat`. I didn't get your idea.

Comment: Do you actually have `altField` hidden input?

Comment: @PeterM I updated the question to answer you.

Comment: Not used CJuiDatePicker myself, but you can convert the posted format with date("d/m/y", strtotime($date));

Comment: @Fred If the related issue is a widget's bug, I'll need to do it!

Comment: Well you'll need to convert it anyway if you want to store it in date format field.

Comment: Read this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345249/jquery-datepicker-altformat-not-displayed

Comment: @ineersa If the dateFormat could return the date in the specified format, I wouldn't need to convert it. But it seems that I can't use the same field for dateFormat and altFormat, right?

Comment: Yes. It must be 2nd hidden field, which you'll path to POST with your alt format. Best way in yii for creating date in your format is extend beforeSave() function in your model and add something like this:`$this->date_create = date('Y-m-d', CDateTimeParser::parse($this->date_create, 'dd.MM.yyyy'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put in the configuration file: 'main.php' something like this:

```
'widgetFactory' => array(
    'widgets' => array(
        'CJuiDatePicker' => array(
            'scriptFile' => 'jquery-ui.min.js',
            'language' => 'en',
            'options' => array(
                'dateFormat' => 'dd/mm/yy',
                'showAnim' => 'fold',
                'fontSize' => '0.85em',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

With this ever that you call a 'CJuiDatePicker' widget will inherit this format.

Comment: This is interesting to do in an application with many instances of CJuiDatePicker. Note: I did just like it is in your code sample, but dateFormat still don't return what I initially expected. But I will use hidden field, just like @ineersa said. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing and have a slightly different solution.
I was mainly looking for on form pages to display the date as DD-MM-YYYY and save in the database as YYYY-MM-DD.

Regardless of changing the dateFormat option on CJuiDatePicker and even trying to use altFormat (using altField as well as apparently this is necessary) option, the date did  not show in the desired format, granted if I were to change the date, the format would be shown correctly.

So I created a Custom class in components and created two methods, one to reformat the date to the DD-MM-YYYY format and one to format the date to the correct YYYY-MM-DD to be saved in the database.
Here is the Custom class (the file is called Custom.php and kept in components.)

```
class Custom
{   
 /* 
 **This method formats the date to be human readble ie 21-06-2013 
 */ 
 public function reformatDate($date)
 {
    if($date == '0000-00-00')
    {
        $newDate = '00-00-0000';
        return $newDate;
    }
    elseif($date == '')
    {
        return $date;
    }
    else
    {
        $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));
        return $newDate;
    }

 }

 /* 
 **This method formats the date to the correct format according to the database 
 */
 public function formatDate($date)
 {
    if($date == '00-00-0000')
    {
        $newDate = '0000-00-00';
        return $newDate;
    }
    elseif($date == '')
    {
        return $date;
    }
    else
    {
        $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
        return $newDate;
    }

 }

}
```

Now that I had methods to change the dates to the correct formats. On the _form page I declared at the top, under the initiation of the form.

```
    $model->date_required = Custom::reformatDate($model->date_required);
    $model->date_created = Custom::reformatDate($model->date_created);
    $model->date_completed = Custom::reformatDate($model->date_completed);
```

This now results in the date being shown correctly, both when the _form page is viewed and the date is changed via the CJuiDatePicker as i still use the dateFormat option to show the correct format when the date is changed.

Lastly I added to both the create and update actions of the controller the following.

```
if(isset($_POST['Tickets']))
    {

        $model->attributes=$_POST['Tickets'];
        $model->date_created = Custom::formatDate($model->date_created);
        $model->date_required = Custom::formatDate($_POST['Tickets']['date_required']);
        $model->date_completed = Custom::formatDate($_POST['Tickets']['date_completed']);
        if($model->save())
```

So before the data is then saved back to the database I format the date to the correct format and pop it into the database.

I'm not expert and only a few month into Yii and about 9 months into PHP. I know there are all sorts of before and after save methods and this may not be the best way to do it, in fact if there is a better way I am all ears. But for now this is working for me. hope ths helps someone.

/* Small Update */
After speaking with a colleague who has been doing this stuff for about a decade. he said it would be much cleaner to remove the code I placed on the form page under the form initiation and move it rather into the controller, so for example my update method appears like so

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{

    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    $model->date_required = Custom::reformatDate($model->date_required);
    $model->date_created = Custom::reformatDate($model->date_created);
    $model->date_completed = Custom::reformatDate($model->date_completed);
```

So rather than reformatting the dates on the form page, it is done directly after loadModel, keeping the view cleaner.