# datepicker format: how do I get a different format behind the scenes?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want the date in the text box to display as `MM-DD-YY (or YYYY, idc)` but for the purposes of MySQL, I need it in `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I have found an identical question here, but I can't get the answer to work on my end. I find the title a little misleading, but the problem as described seems identical to me.

[jQuery datepicker altFormat not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345249/jquery-datepicker-altformat-not-displayed)

The `"altField"` input is because I'm not sure if it's included in the `datepicker`, or if it needed to be added. I can't get it to work either way. The PHP is for my own purposes in debugging, so I can see what is about to be put in the query.

```
<form onsubmit="return(validateEvent())" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<label>Date</label>
<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker">
<br/>
<button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Add Event</button>
<input type="text" name="altField" id="altField" hidden>
```

```
<script>
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        altField: "#altFormat"
    });
});
```

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    echo "<script>";
    $temp = $_POST["datepicker"];
    echo "alert('$temp');";
    echo "</script>";
}
?>
```

Someone please help save my sanity O_o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had wrong id's and the hidden field should have `type=hidden`.

Check this:

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm-dd-yy",
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    altField: "#altField"
  });
  $('#btn1').click(function() {
    console.log("Datepicker value: " + $('#datepicker').val());
    console.log("Datepicker alt value: " + $('#altField').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="" method="post" action="">
  <label>Date</label>
  <input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker">
  <input type="hidden" name="altField" id="altField">
  <br/>
  <button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Add Event</button>
</form>
<br /><br />
<button id="btn1">View Values</button>
```

Comment: Seems to be working now, thank you very much!
You said I had wrong id's though, did you mean there were others aside from altField: "#altField"? (not to be a stickler, just thought you meant I had more)

Comment: @donutguy640, yes, the problem was the you used `altField: "#altFormat"` and you don't have an element with the `id=altFormat`

Answer (score 0):

You cn change the date format to y-m-d

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    echo "<script>";
    $temp = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST["datepicker"]));
    echo "alert('$temp');";
    echo "</script>";
}

?>
```

Comment: There is no reason to use php for that when you can do so with `datepicker`.

Comment: Check my answer. It was both wrong id and hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

The datepicker plugin has a "get" method to return the date type set, we then just need to format this as required. Here we can use datepickers formateDate() method to format before submission.

```
var dateTypeVar = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
$.datepicker.formatDate('Y-m-d', dateTypeVar);
```

https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html